# Handling PDFs as object (embed) in tinyMCE

Tags: object, pdf, tinymce, embed

I cannot seem to get my head around how to handle this in tinyMCE.
We have a lot of official documents stored as PDFs - and we want to be able to embed these in TinyMCE text.
I can see that if we have an already written html text which includes a pdf as an html object, the tinyMCE editor renders the object as an embedded pdf:
[image: PDf embed in TinyMCE]

However we cannot edit the object; it seems unclickable in the editor - and I cannot get my head around how to add a new PDF into the editor - I also cannot find any clues as how to implement the upload/dragndrop functionality to the editor (if thats what we have to do)

Comment: Ok I found some of the solution myself. I have now added a custom button, which can insert a PDF into the tinyMCE textarea as an <object>. However it is not selectable and you cannot drag/drop or change the PDF-link; you can only delete it again using Delete-key. How can I expand the functionality similar to an Image?